# lightbox2 plugin doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, lightbox

I'm getting started with JS, jQuery and so the plugins. On my projects (2 of them), I included [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) plugin, and to my suprise, it works only on 1 of them. I have 'almost' exact code for galleries (almost stands for very little, unmeaning I hope differences). Here are parts of 'gallery' codes:

The working one:

```
<a href="gallery/lotchmiela1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
  <img border="0" src="gallery/small/lotchmiela1.resized.jpg">
</a>

<a href="gallery/lotchmiela2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
  <img border="0" src="gallery/small/lotchmiela2.resized.jpg">
</a>
```

and a not working friend:

```
<a href="photos/img01.jpg" data-lightbox="photos">
  <img class="small"  src="photos/small/img01-small.JPG">
</a>

<a href="photos/img02.jpg" data-lightbox="photos">
  <img class="small"  src="photos/small/img02-small.JPG">
</a>
```

well then, things I've tried:

- switching data-lightbox="..." to rel="lightbox"
- going from .JPG to .jpg (nvm)
- checked the code, script tags 100 times
- pretty much memorized Lightbox2 project site (I did everything there is, twice)

so, reminding you once again that I'm a JS noob, I await for every idea ;)

Comment: There can be few reasons, you sure that you included jQuery in second project? And check firebug console, maybe there you can find reason whats preventing Lightbox from working.

Comment: Check the browser console for error and jQuery include; probably you are not referencing jQuery